# How to see if a directory exists or not in Perl?

Tags: perl, file-io, directory

To see if a file exists before using it, we can use:

```
if (-e "filename.cgi")
{
 #proceed with your code
}
```

But how to indentify a directory exists or not?

Comment: About half of your Perl questions deal with very basic topics. You can save yourself some time if you read some books. [Perl语言入门 ④](http://oreilly.com.cn/book.php?bn=978-7-5641-0636-2), [Learning Perl ⑤](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520113/)

Comment: I'm guessing it took him a very small amount of time to ask these questions, and they are very helpful search results.  Don't be a learning style bigot.

Comment: @Adam I think daxim's point is just that the OP's perl questions (including this one) are all pretty basic and so reading an overview of perl might save some time overall vs asking lots of specific questions whose answers are easily found other ways

Comment: @GreenGiant: I'm quite glad he asked these basic questions, as it means that the answers come up when I search for them.  I suspect that might have been the point of asking them in the first place.

Comment: @daxim There is no minimum complexity required of questions on this site.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use `-d` ([full list of file tests](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html))

```
if (-d "cgi-bin") {
    # directory called cgi-bin exists
}
elsif (-e "cgi-bin") {
    # cgi-bin exists but is not a directory
}
else {
    # nothing called cgi-bin exists
}
```

As a note, `-e` doesn't distinguish between files and directories.  To check if something exists and is a plain file, use `-f`.

Comment: If you're using -d, then you don't need -e (-d returns false for non-existent directories).

Comment: @Peter - while technically correct, in production code it's usually better to do -e followed by -d, so the error messages can be more targeted. There's a difference between "not exist" and "exists as a non-directory" as far as problem resolution in production.