# Perl directory exists equivalent of -e

Tags: perl, directory, file-type, stat

```
-e  File exists.
```

is there one for directory exists? 
because i didnt see it on http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html

Or what would be a best way to test it?

```
next unless (-e $dir . "/dirname");             -e only for file so doesnt work
```

I am trying to avoid doing `opendir and grep` to find the dirname because it seems to be overkill.

updated question:
does perl concat $dir . "/dirname" before doing the -e or -d check?

Comment: -d flag is what you are looking for

Comment: You might also want to read `perldoc -f -X`.

Comment: You seem to be confused. `-e` tells you whether its argument exists; it does not interrogate its inode type.

Comment: @tchrist you are correct. I was confused because Perl used the word "File" and I automatically thought of it as just a file ie not equivalent of a dir. either way, -e should have worked if -d works. neither worked for me for time to debug

Comment: A file is any object in the filesystem: directories and devices and many other things are therefore files as well. See the manpage for the stat(2) system call.

Comment: @tchrist yes i understand that now. just wasnt taught to be see file see any object. anyways, do you know if perl concat before doing -e or -d check?

Comment: @tchrist im wondering if i need to either put () around $dir . "/dirname" before -e or just concat before next unless because its saying dirname exists when it doesnt...

Comment: It’s a simple matter of precedence, per the `perlop` manpage. Plus you can always ask it: `perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e 'print -d $dir . "stuff"'` says `print(-d(($dir . 'stuff')))`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to see if a directory exists or not in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486951/how-to-see-if-a-directory-exists-or-not-in-perl)

Comment: why does this question have -1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `-d` test to see if the given path is a directory. In that case, `-e` will also return true, because that tests for existence of *some* filesystem object.

To see if a path points to a plain file (no directory, no symlink, no special file), use `-f`.

So you want:

```
-d "$dir/dirname" or next;
```

Comment: I know that `-e` is true for directories on Unix-like (and Windows-like) systems, but is it guaranteed for *all* platforms?

Comment: I would strongly suspect so, and can’t find an entry in perlport stating otherwise. Just don’t quote me to it. (But, I mean, what else would `-e` be?)

Comment: My concern is that, IIRC, there is an obscure case on VMS where the same name can refer either to a directory or to a file (I don't recall the details). What should `-e` do if the directory exists and the file doesn't, or vice versa? Not all systems necessarily put directories and files in the same namespace.

Comment: I haver no experience with VMS, but `-e` should return true if `-f` or `-d` (or `-l` (symlink) or any of the other cases). Namespaces should not change this. If in doubt, run a test case.

Comment: `-e` really makes sense only if files and directories are in the same namespace. It happens that they are on most modern systems.

Comment: `-e` works for files, directories, named pipes, devices, and anything else that is part of the file system. `-f` tests for regular files (the ones with data). `-d` tests for directories. `-l` tests for symbolic links.

Comment: @shawnhcorey That’s not quite right. Something like `-e` or `-f` or `-d` **works on symlinks too**, reporting true if the thing **pointed to** by the symlink exists or is a plain file or is a directory. Only `-l` alone will detect a symlink; everything else will go right through it and not distinguish. It has to do with whether stat(2) vs lstat(2) is actually called.