# How to check permission to directory and make new one

Tags: linux, perl

I have script in Perl. I check if user passed an arguments in pattern `-d dir_name`.

```
my $len = @ARGV;

    if($len == 2 ){
        if($ARGV[0] eq "-d"){
            $passed_name=$ARGV[1];
            return;
        }
    }
```

user passes second argument like `/this/is/path/dir_name`
Now I want to check if user has permission to this directory, and then check if `dir_name` exists (if not - I have to make it).

Comment: `perldoc -f mkdir`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4486951/725418

Comment: What is your question about Perl?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Now I want to check if user has permission to this directory, and then check if dir_name exists (if not - I have to make it).

"Check then do" invites a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), if two things try the same thing at the same time one will fail.

```
     Process 1           Process 2
-----------------------------------
|    Check "dir"                
|                        Check "dir"
t    mkdir "dir"
i    success             
m                        mkdir "dir"
e                        error, it already exists
|
V
```

Instead, do it and decide what to do if there's an error.

Perl's error checking is based on [C's errno.h](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html). To check what type of error happened, look to see if the error is true in the `%!` hash. In this case we're looking for `EEXIST` (file exists).

```
# It did not make the directory, and it wasn't because it already existed.
if( !mkdir $passed_name and !$!{EEXIST} ) {
    die "Could not create $passed_name: $!";
}
else {
    print "$passed_name was created, or it already existed.\n";
}
```

Note that [`mkdir`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir) will not make the necessary subdirectories. `/this/is/path/` must exist to make `/this/is/path/dir_name`. If you want it to make the subdirectories, use [`make_path` from File::Path](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Path). Or better yet, the excellent [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny).

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# vim: ai ts=4 sw=4

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Errno;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
use Pod::Usage;

my %opt;
my @args = (
            'dir|d=s',
            'help|?',
            'man|m'
        );

GetOptions( \%opt, @args ) or pod2usage(2);

pod2usage(1) if $opt{help};
pod2usage(-exitval => 0, -verbose => 2) if $opt{man};

die 'Specify parameter -d [dirname]' unless $opt{dir};

if( -e $opt{dir} and -d $opt{dir} ) {
    say 'Directory exist';
    say 'Readable   by effective uid/gid'   if -r $opt{dir};
    say 'Writable   by effective uid/gid'   if -w $opt{dir};
    say 'Executable by effective uid/gid'   if -x $opt{dir};
    say 'Readable   by real uid/gid'        if -R $opt{dir};
    say 'Writable   by real uid/gid'        if -W $opt{dir};
    say 'Executable by real uid/gid'        if -X $opt{dir};
    say 'Owned  by real uid'                if -O $opt{dir};
} else {
    unless ( mkdir $opt{dir} ) {
        say 'Failed to create' if $!{EEXIST};
    }
}

__END__

=head1 NAME

dir_exist.pl - checks if directory exists

=head1 SYNOPSIS

 dir_exist.pl [options] file(s)

 Options:
    -d,--dir    dirname to create
    -?,--help   brief help message
    -m,--man    full documentation

=head1 OPTIONS

=over 4

=item B<-d,--dir>

Specifies directory name as a parameter

=item B<-?,--help>

Print a brief help message and exits.

=back

=head1 DESCRIPTION

B<This program> accepts B<input> and processes to B<output> with purpose of achiving some goal.

=head1 EXIT STATUS

The section describes B<EXIT STATUS> codes of the program

=head1 ENVIRONMENT

The section describes B<ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES> utilized in the program

=head1 FILES

The section describes B<FILES> which used for program's configuration

=head1 EXAMPLES

The section demonstrates some B<EXAMPLES> of the code

=head1 REPORTING BUGS

The section provides information how to report bugs

=head1 AUTHOR

The section describing author and his contanct information

=head1 ACKNOWLEDGMENT

The section to give credits people in some way related to the code

=head1 SEE ALSO

The section describing related information - reference to other programs, blogs, website, ...

=head1 HISTORY

The section gives historical information related to the code of the program

=head1 COPYRIGHT

Copyright information related to the code

=cut
```

Documentation:

- [Errno](https://perldoc.perl.org/Errno)
- [POSIX](https://perl.developpez.com/documentations/en/5.12.3/POSIX.html#ERRNO)
- [File test operators](https://www.perltutorial.org/perl-file-test-operators/)